# Android Error: Unable to find explicit activity class

Tags: java, android

As you can see in MainActivity.java, I am trying to show data, stored in SQLiteDatabse to List View but when data is already stored in database and **else** part run, my application get crashed at this point on going to **showdata.class** activity.

**MainActivity.java**

package com.example.crudwithlist;

```
public void onShow(View view) {

        Database database=new Database(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db= database.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM PRODUCT",new String[]{});

        if(cursor.getCount()==0)
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Saved Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        else{
            Intent intent= new Intent(this,showdata.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

**showdata.java**

package com.example.crudwithlist;

```
public class showdata extends AppCompatActivity {


    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_showdata);
        
        //Calling showData method
        showData();

    }

    public void showData(){
        new Database(this);
        new ArrayList<String>();
        db=database.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM PRODUCT",new String[]{});

        while(cursor.moveToNext()){

            id=cursor.getInt(0);
            name=cursor.getString(1);
            des=cursor.getString(2);
            price=cursor.getDouble(3);
            list.add("id : "+id+"\t"+"Name : "+name+"\t"+"Description : "+des+"\t"+"Price : "+price+"\n");

        }

        new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.datastyle,list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.crudwithlist">

    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.CRUDwithList">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Error at Line, in MainActivity.java**

```
**

62> startActivity(intent);

**
```

**Error Description**

```
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.crudwithlist/com.example.crudwithlist.showdata}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

at com.example.crudwithlist.MainActivity.onShow(MainActivity.java:62)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the class is not included in the manifest file.

If you look, you'll notice that following code is in your manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

You will have to do pretty much the same for your showdata.java class.

Solution. Add this to your Android Manifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".showdata"/>
```